# Application access its own version in mercurial repository

Tags: python, mercurial

I have application I want to print out (in "about" box) its revision/version from mercurial. Suppose it is revision `deadbeef` so it will know that. In old times in CVS could use something like `$Revision$` to substitute automatically.

What is best practice with Mercurial for this?

Comment: Where, exactly, is this "about" box? In the application's GUI?

Comment: @Matt: suppose yes, or web app maybe, or just a printout in command-line program, does it matters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial's [Keyword Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeywordExtension) is probably what you want. It supports the `$Revision$` format pretty much exactly.

Answer (score 5):

The best approach is probably to use precommit hook to replace a designated file with the output of `hg log -r tip`, possibly with a `--template` arg to format it in a particular way.

Unfortunately, there's a bit of a chicken and egg problem.  The revision is a checksum of the commited data, but the checksum is not available until after the commit has taken place.  One option might be to actually hook on commit instead of precommit, and commit the version info in a seperate changeset.

Comment: so because of chicken-egg problem you say, i can't actually use pre-commit hook?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to put in the file.  If you want the actual revision id, then no, the id of the in-flight changeset is not known at precommit.  You'd have to use the commit hook instead and make a second commit.

Comment: I solved the chicken/egg problem by setting my (C++) code to #include a file that is ignored by Mercurial. A pre-compilation step of the build generates the file (I used `hg id` but the theory is the same)... as it's ignored by Mercurial, it doesn't affect the changeset. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to get the current revision in mercurial:

```
hg id -i
```